# Recommendations for bluetooth headset that work in headset mode

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone

Could you recommend bluetooth headsets that will work in headset mode (with headphones AND mic; HSP/HFP) on Ubuntu 20.04? I have the Bose QCII and the Soundcore Q20, but neither work  (in HSP/HFP). I have tried various things to try to make them work, but without success.

Are there any bluetooth headsets that work (in HSP/HFP) out of the box (on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)?

Many thanks!

(It may also be that this is not an issue with the headset, but with 20.04 LTS. Could somebody confirm that? And confirm that this has been fixed in 20.10 and/or this remains fixed in the upcoming 22.04 LTS?)

Comment: ehm. the Bose does work with hsp? The soundcre I doubt it does. I have a rolfstone. Works perfectly for anything bt related and lasts a 70 hour :) What matters MORE is your NIC/BT device. Does it support 4.2 or 5.0?

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. By NIC/BT you mean the chip in my laptop? How would I figure out whether it is 4.2 or 5.0?

Comment: Just to add that the bluetooth devices I have all work under Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell XPS 9310.